# Black box at bottom of transparent Android app

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making an Android app that's transparent and there's this black box at the bottom how do I remove it I'm on a Pixel 3 with Android 12 Graphene OS

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was my wallpaper that had a black box lmao

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).